# Select count(*) from A update in B Super Slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, count, sql-update

I have a query that takes 2minutes to count from table A and update Table B with the count result.

Everytime that a number in Table_B column Start matches the range in Table_A (readstart/readend) I should update read_count in Table_B.

```
   id | readstart | readend | read_count
    1 | 2999997   | 3000097  | 0   
    2 | 3000097   | 3000197  | 0   
    3 | 3000497   | 3000597  | 0   
    4 | 3001597   | 3001697  | 0   
    5 | 3001897   | 3001997  | 0   
    6 | 3005397   | 3005497  | 0   
    7 | 3005997   | 3006097  | 0  
    8 | 3006397   | 3006497  | 0   
    9 | 3006797   | 3006897  | 0  
    10| 3007497   | 3007597  | 0
```

Here is the table I should update with the count result :

```
    CREATE TABLE `rdc_test` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `readstart` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `readend` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `read_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `readstart` (`readstart`),
     KEY `readend` (`readend`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is the table from where I wanna count matching rows :

```
   CREATE TABLE `1ips_chr1` (
   `strand` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `chr` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
   `start` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `end` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `name2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `start` (`start`),
   KEY `end` (`end`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=34994289 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I did a test on 10 rows, the result was horrible..2 minutes to select count(*) and update 10 rows. I have about 350,000 rows in Table_A to update and 35,000,000 in table_B. I know that in average each count should return 30~40 as a result.

Here is my super slow query :

```
UPDATE rdc_test
SET rdc_test.read_count =
    ( 
        SELECT COUNT(start) as read_count 
        FROM 1ips_chr1
        WHERE 1ips_chr1.start >= rdc_test.readstart 
        AND 1ips_chr1.start <= rdc_test.readend
    )

Query OK, 10 rows affected (2 min 22.20 sec)
Rows matched: 10  Changed: 10  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: How much time the inner `SELECT COUNT(start)..` statement takes?

Comment: @madkitty You can use `count(*)` instead of `count(start)`, because your `WHERE` clause automatically filters out the rows when `start = NULL` in this particular case. Maybe not much but this way you may get a little performance benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
UPDATE rdc_test t1
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT r.id AS id, 
               COUNT(l.start) AS read_count
        FROM rdc_test r
            LEFT OUTER JOIN start1ips_chr1 l
                ON l.start >= r.readstart 
                AND l.start <= r.readend
        GROUP BY r.id
    ) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.read_count =  t2.read_count
```

Edit :

Due to the amount of datas you need to update, the best way is to recreate the table instead of perform an update :

```
CREATE TABLE new_rdc_test AS
SELECT r.id AS id, 
       r.readstart AS readstart,
       r.readend AS readend,
       COUNT(l.start) AS read_count
FROM rdc_test r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN start1ips_chr1 l
        ON l.start >= r.readstart 
        AND l.start <= r.readend
GROUP BY r.id, r.readstart, r.readend
```

Does this query run fast enough ?

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN l.start1ips_chr1 l >> here you meant  LEFT OUTER JOIN l.start AS 1ips_chr1 l ?

Comment: Query OK, 0 rows affected (2 min 26.20 sec)
Rows matched: 10  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: @madkitty : yup, I wrote CREATE nameTable, but it is CREATE TABLE nameTable.

Comment: @ Scorpi0 : I queried this :            `mysql> CREATE table new_rdc_test AS
   -> SELECT r.id AS id,
    ->        r.readstart AS readstart,
    ->        r.readend AS readend,
    ->        COUNT(l.start) AS read_count
    -> FROM rdc_test r
    ->     LEFT OUTER JOIN 1ips_chr1 l
    ->         ON l.start >= r.readstart
    ->         AND l.start <= r.readend
    -> GROUP BY r.id, r.readstart, r.readend;`

Comment: `Query OK, 10 rows affected (2 min 23.63 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0` lol I think there's no solution .. I should just give up MySQL ㅠ.ㅠ

Comment: @ Scorpi0 :Maybe it could be faster if I switch to MyISAM. Neway thks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to bring the `COUNT(*)` to application level (ie. store it as a variable in PHP/Java) then do the `UPDATE`, with that value. MySQL will not have to calculate that count for every record you update.

Comment: thanks but that means I should use PHP to generate that query?

Comment: Not necessarily PHP - I assume you use the DB in an application - use the language of that application to execute those queries